# Brother 2270DW network setup

Tags: printer, printing

I recently got a Brother 2270DW laser printer for my dorm room.  Since I am at college and I don't want to put my personal printer on the campus network so I just got a USB cable to wire it to my laptop.  This has been fine up until now.

There are some settings on the printer that I need to change, and the configuration is through a web app, but since I am connected via USB my printer doesn't have an IP address that I can use to get to the network dialog.

How can I access this printers settings without connecting it to a network?

EDIT: Thanks for the two responses thus far.  I can print just fine, but I don't have control over the setting of the printer other than what's included in the windows dialog.  I would like to make the printer keep on printing even when the toner is low, which is something that can only be changed though the web dialog that I don't have access to.

Comment: I believe you can enable Toner Continue mode by pressing the Go button 7 times.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Did you use the latest driver offered by Brother?  Why not just set up an Ad-Hoc wireless network between (just) you and the printer?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say in cases when you aren't connected via network, the only other method is to have the software provided with the printer in order to access its configuration. If you don't have this, you can find it here.

https://www.brother-usa.com/support/ModelInfo.aspx?R3ModelID=HL2270DW#.Unf6vHBwpWS

Answer (score 1):

This was a while ago I had an older brother wireless laser printer.  In order to configure the wireless settings, you had to connect it via USB and use the configuration software that came on the CD with the printer.  This may have changed, but from the issue you are having, it seems to be the same.